# UICollectionViewCell make font bold on selection and regular when deselected - Memory footprint

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, didselectrowatindexpath

When a cell is selected , the subclass method overrides the **setSelected:**

**View Controller Code**

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

**CollectionView Subclass Method**

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected{
    [super setSelected:selected];
    if(self.isSelected){


        self.myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.0];
    }else{
        self.myLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
    }
}
```

I am also trying to change the textcolor. So, is it like every time I select new **UIFont**  objects will be created , also if set text color (some custom UIColor) will new objects be created. Or is there is any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

The view controller code is redundant. The system will automatically do all of that.

With regard to creating UIFont objects, the overhead is minimal, and you don't need to worry about that.